# solr : not searchable text index and store after copyField

Tags: solr, schema

I am new to solr
Ideally, trying to keep the field A and B be stored but not indexed.
and copy the fields content to "*text*" for general search
where "*text*" just keeping the index but not store

schema:

```
<field name="_text_" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
<field name="field_A" type="text_en" indexed="false" stored="true"/>
<field name="field_B" type="text_en" indexed="false" stored="true"/>

<copyField dest="_text_" source="field_A"/>
<copyField dest="_text_" source="field_B"/>
```

(using the out of the box fieldtype section for text_general and text_en)

It seems the value being copied to "*text*" but not searchable at
(using default search df on config).

It was if I indexed=true on both field_A and B

Is the direction I am moving on correct?

Comment: Your setup should work as expected as long as you're searching in the `_text_` field and not in either of the `field_`-fields.

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you could post the query you are using. The whole URL, including all parameters. That would allow people to try to reproduce the problem.